# Cannot play video *.mp4 in sdCard by SurfaceView android

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I have a video .mp4 in sdCard ,If play video by VideoView it play Ok .But if 
I use SurfaceView to play this video .I can not play .Please help me .Thank you so much !.This is my code to play video use SurfaceView

```
String pathVideo = watchIntent.getStringExtra("pathFileVideo");
        SurfaceHolder videoHolder = videoSurface.getHolder();
        videoHolder.addCallback(this);
        mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        controller = new VideoControllerView(mContext);
        try {
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(pathVideo);
            mPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (SecurityException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Share the code please

Comment: This is my code to play video by SurfaceView :